# Oracle cursor leak after upgrading oracle driver

Tags: java, oracle12c, connection-pooling, tomcat8, ucp

I'm facing a pretty intermittent issue related to oracle cursor leak. Our system runs on oracle 12.2.0.1 database. As per the oracle documentation suggested we recently upgraded our oracle connection pool to universal connection pool( also ojdbc7 to ojdbc8, ucp and ons ), since oracle data source has some deprecated functions comparing with our database. After doing this i'm facing a cursor leak in a query which is worked for many years back. We have maximum of 3000 cursors declared in our system and after starting a one app server cursor limit is getting excedded. Please give me a idea about this.

Note: I can update this with the databse information if needed.

Comment: Pardon me for asking the obvious question. Are you closing your cursors?

Comment: Yes @Abra implicitly ( I only facing this after the upgrade )

Comment: Sometimes two mistakes may cancel each other out. I'm only guessing, but there may have been a bug in an earlier Oracle version regarding closing of cursors. And if your code contains a bug, then because of the Oracle bug it did not manifest itself. Now if that Oracle bug is corrected in 12.2.0.1 it may be the reason that suddenly the bug in your code is exposed. I suggest re-examining your code for unclosed cursors. Alternatively, perhaps the method for implicitly closing cursors has changed in Oracle 12.2.0.1. Worth investigating, no?

Comment: Yes @Abra absolutely, will check it. Thank you for your opinion.